# Toggle Wifi for personal Application

Tags: iphone, wifi

How to create dylib for springboard and how to use the mobile substrate? Cannot find info, need to create an app to programatically toggle wifi module for any iOS version 3.0 to 4.1. Is creating springboard dylib the solution for my app? Thanks in advance!